# problem with directly calling class methods using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-class

Here is the code without multiprocessing that works. It outputs 144.

```
class persons():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = None
        self.num2 = None
        
    def weird_squaring_algo(self, num1):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = 10
        
        self.func1(num1)

        return self.num2
        
    def func1(self, mul):
        self.num2 = self.num1 * mul
        return

p = persons()
p.weird_squaring_algo(12)
```

And when I want to do this using multiprocessing it doesn't seem to work. It outputs 10.

```
class persons():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = None
        self.num2 = None
        
    def weird_squaring_algo(self, num1):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = 10
        pool = mp.Pool(8)
        r = pool.map(self.func1, [num1])
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return self.num2
        
    def func1(self, mul):
        self.num2 = self.num1 * mul
        return

p = persons()
p.weird_squaring_algo(13)
```

What am I doing wrong in the second code?

Comment: You have a one-thread calculation - what do yuo want to do in concurrent mode? 2) you can't access class properties dynamically. There are mp.Value for that

Comment: Multiprocessing runs in another process and does not modify instances in the calling process. Do a broader search and you will find many questions like this one

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Multiprocessing does not pass the original object back to the caller.

**corrected code**

```
class persons():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = None
        self.num2 = None
        
    def weird_squaring_algo(self, num1):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = 10
        pool = mp.Pool(8)
        self.num2 = pool.map(self.func1, [num1])[0]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return self.num2
        
    def func1(self, mul):
        self.num2 = self.num1 * mul
        return self.num2

p = persons()
p.weird_squaring_algo(13)
```